# Do all verbs become Ichidan once in their Potential Form?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, conditionals, potential-form, ichidan-verbs

Question again from 君の名は manga:

“夢**だけでも**、男の子に**なれたら**なぁ”

I'm unsure about my understanding of the verb conjugation.. is this the potential form of なる plus the conditional form ~たら.. ? Checking the rules to conjugate to ~たら form, なれる being a Godan verb, will become = ～なれったら, no...?

Also, I’ve learned about だけ which means “only,” but what about でも in this case? What pattern is this?

Comment: You put two questions in one post. I would suggest you ask the last part in a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every verb that has the /e/ vowel sound immediately before ます in its ます-form is an *ichidan* (or Group-II) verb, and every potential verb, with the only exception of the irregular できる, meets this condition. できる also happens to be an *ichidan* verb. So, yes, all potential verbs are *ichidan* verbs.

なる (なります) itself is a *godan* (or Group-I) verb, but its potential form なれる (なれます /nar**e**masu/) is an *ichian* verb, and therefore, it becomes なれたら when it is followed by たら.